# Depth First Search is running into java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I'm running into a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when I use depth first search on a undirected graph to determine if node1 is reachable to node2. The code is listed below. (some irrelevant details are intended to be removed.)

```
    //definition of nodes and edges
    Set<Node> nodes = new HashSet<Node>();
    Map<Node, Set<Node>> edges = new HashMap<Node, Set<Node>>();

    //method to determine if node1 is reachable to node2    
    public boolean isReachable(int p1, MethodNode m1, ClassNode c1, int p2, MethodNode m2, ClassNode c2) {  
            Node node1 = new Node (p1,m1,c1);
        Node node2 = new Node (p2,m2,c2);

            Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();

        stack.push(node1);
        while(!stack.isEmpty()){

            Node current = null;
            current = stack.pop();
                    //test current node, if its child nodes contains node2, return true
                    //otherwise, push its child nodes into stack
            for(final Node temp : edges.get(current)){
                if(temp.equals(node2)){
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    stack.push(temp);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
}
```

I guess there must be some infinite calls that run out of memory, but I can't locate it.

Comment: why dont you use dijstras shortest path algorithm?

Comment: I just try to implement DFS and BFS to familiarize Stack and Queue in Java. @AlexWien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem

```
for (final Node temp : edges.get(current)){
    if(temp.equals(node2)){
        return true;
    } else {
        stack.push(temp);
    }
}
```

This will push all neighbors on the stack, then take one of them, push all its neighbors on the stack (including the one you started at), and so on ad infinitum. You need to mark nodes as visited so this doesn't happen. The only cases you won't be getting an infinite loop are when either the node you're looking for is directly adjacent to the node you start at or if the nodes on the path to it are put onto the stack in the correct order by pure chance.

Comment: Clear explanation. Thanks a lot. I've figured out this problem. @G.Bach

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your code is susceptible to chasing its own tail: if a graph contains a cycle, your code will exhaust the stack, because it does not check if a vertex has been explored before pushing it onto the stack.

[Basic DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) requires you to maintain a set of explored vertices, and explore a vertex only if it is unexplored. Adding this set to your program should address the out-of-memory problem.

Comment: Thank you. Both G.Bach and you give good help to me. It's really hard to choose a best answer. @dasblinkenlight

Answer (score 1):

With your algorithm, if the graph has a cycle, it will keep pushing elements of the cycle onto the stack until you run out of memory. You need to keep track of which nodes have already been explored and avoid pushing them onto the stack. There are several standard algorithms for doing this (A<sup>*</sup> and Dijkstra come to mind). See the Wikipedia article on [depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an extra

> List< Nodes > traversed = new ArrayList< Nodes >();

In this you can keep the nodes that you are pushing on to the stack.
Perform 1 step before pushing it on to the stack

```
if(!traversed.contains(temp)) {
stack.push(temp);
}
```